# How to find the element described in Sylow II

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

I'm currently doing this question:

> Find two Sylow $3$-subgroups $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$ of the alternating group $A_{4}$ and an element $\sigma \in A_{4}$ such that $H_{2}= \sigma H_1\sigma^{−1}$.

I can do the first part and found $H_{1}=\{1, (123), (132)\}$ and $H_{2}=\{1, (134), (143)\}$.

I'm not sure how to do the second part of the question, it says $\sigma=(234)$ and I can do the calculation to prove it but I'm not sure how they found the answer. Do I just have to trial and error elements in $A_{4}$ until I find it?

Comment: Yes, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) for the $3$-Sylow subgroups. There are not so many choices for such a $\sigma$ here. Try a few ones to see that several ones won't work anyway.

Comment: @DietrichBurde is there not a faster way of finding them than just doing trial and error? Surely there has to be for the instances of bigger groups than $A_{4}$?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Use, for example, `$\sigma=(12)\in X$` for $\sigma=(12)\in X$.

Comment: A faster way of doing this question would have been to choose $H_1$ and $\sigma$ first, and then define $H_2 =\sigma H_1\sigma^{-1}$ (but choose a different $\sigma$ if $H_2=H_1$).